# ChartistJS Angular2 - chart only rendering after resizing window

Tags: angular, rendering, chartist.js

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to render a chart using ChartistJS

Whats weird is that if i resize the window my charts data displays.

This suggests I'm rendering the Chart with incomplete data.

Currently I am using my API service to get my data.

I found this link which looks like a similar solved problem but really struggling to implement it.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component?rq=1)

Below is my component

I would love your help here please

Thanks

GWS

**chartistJs.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, 
  ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartistJsService } from './chartistJs.service';
import { PortfolioReturns } from './returns-interface';
import { BaThemeConfigProvider } from '../../../../theme';

@Component({
  selector: 'chartist-js',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('chartist/dist/chartist.css'), require('./chartistJs.scss')],
  template: require('./chartistJs.html'),
  providers: [ ChartistJsService ]  
})

export class ChartistJs {
  
  errorMessage: string;
  returns: PortfolioReturns[];
  arr = [];
  seriesdata = [];
  lablesdata = [];
  isDataAvailable : boolean = true;

  data = {
    simpleLineOptions: {},
    simpleLineData: {}
  };

  constructor( private _chartistJsService: ChartistJsService, 
  private _baConfig: BaThemeConfigProvider,
  private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {     
    this.ChartistChart();
     }

ChartistChart() {

 let chartdata = {
  labels: this.getlablesdata(),
  series: [ this.getseriesdata(),
  ]
};

 this.data = {
    simpleLineOptions: {
      color: this._baConfig.get().colors.defaultText,
      fullWidth: true,
      height: '300px',
      chartPadding: {
        right: 40
      }
    },
    simpleLineData: chartdata
    };
 }

 getseriesdata() {
   this._chartistJsService.getReturns()
            .subscribe((res: PortfolioReturns[]) => {
                this.returns = res;
                for (let i = 0; i < this.returns.length; ++i) {
                   this.seriesdata.push(this.returns[i].logReturnGross.toString());
    }} );
    return this.seriesdata;
  }

 getlablesdata() {
   this._chartistJsService.getReturns()
            .subscribe((res: PortfolioReturns[]) => {
                this.returns = res;
                for (let i = 0; i < this.returns.length; ++i) {
                   this.lablesdata.push(this.returns[i].performanceDate);
                  }} ) ;
    return this.lablesdata;
  }


   getResponsive(padding, offset) {
    return this._chartistJsService.getResponsive(padding, offset);
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a plunker example?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I understand it's hard to tell from the snippet. I'm really struggling to try and reproduced an example given the complexity of the base project I'm really unsure how long that will take me.

I've raised the issue with the dashboard framework I've forked https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by .subscribe after my Http Get

```
ChartistChart() {
    this._chartistJsService.getReturns()
        .subscribe((res: PortfolioReturns[])  => {
            this.returns = res;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.returns.length; ++i) {
               this.seriesdata.push(this.returns[i].logReturnGross);
               this.lablesdata.push(this.returns[i].performanceDate.toString());
              };
               this.data = {   
                simpleLineOptions: {
                  color: this._baConfig.get().colors.defaultText,
                  fullWidth: true,
                  height: '300px',
                  chartPadding: {
                    right: 40
                  }
                },
                simpleLineData: {
                  labels: this.lablesdata,
                  series: [ this.seriesdata ]
                }
                };
            });
        }
```