# Not able to get dynamic translation of text using ngx translate/core - angular 2 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

**Problem :**

I have dynamic text that is coming from Json file.
I am using translate.get() method like this:

```
this.translate.get('keyInJson').subscribe(res => { 
                this.valueFromJson = res;
/*
creating an object using above text
*/
            });
```

As this is asynchronous I am not able to get the translated text when the page renders.
I tried wrapping above method inside Observables , Promises but it's not able to get translated version of text during page load.
I was able to get the translated text after trying different approaches but code became too complex and not reliable.

**Expected/desired behavior**
Should load translated version of text

**Reproduction of the problem**
Dynamically generate the text instead of hardcoding it on html and then try to render translated version.

**Environment**
Angular2 , Typescript, Ionic 2

Comment: The code sample you posted isn't valid typescript code.  Yout have a html <br> element in the middle of that statement.  Please fix your code in your question.

Comment: Edited the description

Comment: Could you provide more context of where the example code resides and where `valueFromJson` is used? If the above code is in, for example, the constructor of a component, and you want to use the value in the component's template, then you should be able to put `{{valueFromJson}}` in the template without issue.

Comment: The example code resides in a function in global service, which I have injected in to my component. I am calling this function from a component's ngOnInit.

Comment: duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component

Comment: @masterach are you using `@ngx-translate/http-loader@0.1.0` ?

Comment: When does the translated text need to be available? How is it used?

Answer (score 13):

[@nkadu1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43004797/2215563)

> instant(key: string|Array, interpolateParams?: Object): string|Object: Gets the **instant translated value** of a key (or an array of keys). This method is **synchronous** and the default file loader is asynchronous. **You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method**.

```
const translated = this.translate.instant('keyInJson');
```

---

[@masterach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104324/masterach) [TranslateHttpLoader](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader) is what you're looking for. [Here's an article](https://medium.com/@TuiZ/how-to-split-your-i18n-file-per-lazy-loaded-module-with-ngx-translate-3caef57a738f) which might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

I been using @ngx-translate from a while right now. I use the module in two ways:

1. Using the pipe:

> {{'code_to_translate' | translate }}

1. Using the service

> const translateText: string =
>   this.translateService.instant('code_to_translate')

the translate service should be passed in the constructor of you component (or service )

usually I declare the string result in my app.ini function before load the components and use only one translation service for my entire application. 
I also declare my custom TranslateLoader to manage the source of translations from any place (external api, json file, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the pipe in html instead of translating in ts?

```
<div>{{ 'HELLO' | translate:param }}</div>
```

or

```
<div [innerHTML]="'HELLO' | translate"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your global service:

```
private _valueFromJson: string;
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.get('keyInJson').subscribe(res => { 
    this._valueFromJson = res;
  });
}
get valueFromJson() {
  return this._valueFromJson;
}
```

Or:

```
public valueFromJson: string;
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  translate.get('keyInJson').subscribe(res => { 
    this.valueFromJson = res;
  });
}
```

Then, in your component template you can bind directly:

```
<div>{{ globalService.valueFromJson }}</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a [synchronous method](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods):

```
this.valueFromJson = translate.instant('keyInJson');
```