# ngx-translate for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I'm new to Angular, I'm using ngx-translate all over my app and it is working fine however, I'm not able to figure out how to translate dynamic data even after searching all over the internet I couldn't quite understand how to achieve this, below is what I've tried, your assistance is much appreciated.

en.json

```
"STATUS_ACTIVE": "Active"
```

employees.component.html

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of employees">
    <tr *ngFor="let employeeStatus of item.employeeJobStatuses">
      <td>{{ item.firstName_FL }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.position.name_FL }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.hiringDate | date }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.firstContractingSalary }}</td>
      <td>{{ (employeeStatus.status) | translate }}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <p><i type="button" (click)="editEmployee(item.id)" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></p>
          <p class="action-center" translate>employees.terminate</p>
          <p translate>employees.suspend</p>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Please help me out translate employeeStatus.status

Comment: What does `employeeStatus.status` contain?

Comment: It contains a string "STATUS_ACTIVE"

Comment: Shouldn't your translation file `en.json` have a key `{ "STATUS_ACTIVE": "Active" }`?

Comment: yes, I actually put it like this but it's not translating

Comment: What will be the value of `employeeStatus.status`? Is it `STATUS_ACTIVE` or just `Active`?

Comment: I want the translation to display "Active" however the response that I receive displays STATUS_ACTIVE

Comment: Have you added `HttpLoaderFactory` and `TranslateHttpLoader` in `app.module.ts` ? Can you post that code?

Comment: export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

Actually the translation is working fine, it's just with dynamic data

Comment: Try to use `this.translate.instant()` method refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004797/not-able-to-get-dynamic-translation-of-text-using-ngx-translate-core-angular-2

Comment: I've tried this example but still no joy, do you have any other recommendations ?

Comment: I have created a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-example-czucpk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for you. It just works.

Comment: @Silvermind You really saved the day, It is working perfectly now, thank you so much !

Comment: @Silvermind But the question is about dynamic data. If user open application then he change data on server are user will have instant update on his application ?

Comment: @Silvermind Yes, this is well handled, thank you though

Comment: @Silvermind Or sorry i was wrong maybe it should be questioned like "real time data" instead of "dynamic data". XD In case real time data he should create custom made loader and set there observable who will update translation with no any action.

Comment: @Omar what was the actual issue in your code?

Comment: The problem was very silly to be honest, I was putting the translated string in an object, so I just removed it from the object

Comment: @Mises If either the language or the property value changes, the display will be updated.

Comment: @Silvermind Yeah but you got on mind event emited by user. I am thinking about real time data game where all data goes through @ngx-translate/core. User will not see any changes until he make some move or you implement on custom made loader a listener.

Comment: @Mises Perhaps a good question to post on so?