# Angular 2, How to store value in variable from ngOnInit()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Here when I login to my app, i want to get json object stored in local Storage and then assign it to user Object. First time if I login it won't show anything but if I refresh the page I can see first name.

Here is .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-navbar',
    templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
    user: Object;
    ngOnInit() {
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    }
}
```

And in template I want to use it like this:

```
<p> {{ user.first_name }} </p>
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: @Vega no. That's a bad suggestion

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Comment: What is inside the user object? you can view it in the html by using {{user | json}} or just console.log it.

Comment: Seems like you snippet is incomplete. How are you injecting `localStorage`? Post some more relevant code

Comment: @dag sessionStorage and localStorage is globally available...

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot about it @Carsten

Comment: @dag 
`localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));`
in log i'm getting user object also. just can't print it first time in my template.

Comment: Not sure but you can try this: <p> {{ user?.first_name }} </p>

Comment: please the whole code on plunk and share the link

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing. i'm new to angluar 2 and i integrated login with node js  api. when i log in i store data in local storage and after on another page i want to access that local storage data. Problem is `this.user` doesn't print data first time. i have to refresh page to print data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After proper searching, found my answer here.

[Angular2: How to load data before rendering the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component)

@Wesley Coetzee, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 7):

Your html is rendering before the variable is being set

Inside your html use this:

```
<p> {{ user?.first_name }} </p>
```

This is called the Safe Navigation Operator which will prevent the error and render the `first_name` when it is populated.

Comment: Thanks. But my question is how i can set variable with value before html render, since i want to use it's value in my template.

Comment: Since this is a binding, it will update in your template when the user variable changes in your typescript. So initially, `user` might be null and nothing will show in the `<p>`, but it will update after you set `user`. This seems like the right answer.