# Using Resolve or promise/Observables in angular2 to get result from Firebase connection before component is rendered

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

```
constructor(private router: Router){
  //Initiate Firebase Connection
    fireApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            fireApp.database().ref('/notifications/' + user.uid).on('value', data => {
                if (data.val()) {
                    this.notificationCount = data.val().notification.length}
            });
        } else {
            this.httpService.fetchData('get', 'v1/notification/auth', function (data) {
                data = data.json();
                try {
                    fireApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(data.FBToken).then
                         (function (signeduser) {
                         fireApp.database().ref('/notifications/' + signeduser.uid).on
                         ('value', data => {
                            if (data.val()) {
                                this.notificationCount = data.val().length
                         }
                        });
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw err;
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log((<Error>e).message);//conversion to Error type
                }
            }, {});
        }
    });
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
}
```

And then inside getData function I want notificationCount value which I should be receiving from firebase Connection

```
getData(){
  console.log(this.notificationCount)
 }
```

I get `notificationCount` when component loads as event for Firebase connection takes time to return the result(Firebase connection returns the result but after component is rendered), how `notificationCount` value can be retrieved before the component is rendered using resolve or promise in this scenario, as I haven't used resolve in Angular 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: How to load data before rendering the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component)

Comment: Please could you give a hint as to how can I apply promise to Firebase event I tried referring to the above query before I had posted this, thanks