# Daxie & Angular : Wait until populating DB

Tags: angular, dexie

i have a service PhoneService calling (in the constructor) a remote API to get data and populate DB, the AppComponent use the PhoneService (ngOnInit) to get data from Dexie table.
in the first page load i have no data (it's normal because AppComponent call function to get data before the PhoneService populate Dexie DB)

my question is : how can i tell my PhoneService to wait unit pupulation ending and then fetch the Dexie table to get data ?

**First page load :** Check if Data in my Dexie Table (0 record) -> Calling API -> Populate Dexie DB -> fetch Dexie Table (No data because angular fetch Dexie table before, data population end )

**Second+ page load :** Check if Data in my Dexie Table (ok) -> fetch Dexie Table (OK)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

typically, you have to use promises to synchronise everything.

Have a look at this thread, you will understand :
[Angular2: How to load data before rendering the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component?rq=1)

Comment: thanks @sancelot, I have no problem when I use direct call to my API, the problem is when I : Call API -> populate DB -> fetch Dexie Table