# Is there a possibility to load services before components?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component `SurveyComponent` and a service `SurveyService`. The `SurveyService` loads some data form JSON.

I add the `SurveyService` into the constructor from `SurveyComponent`.

```
constructor(public surveyService: SurveyService) {}
```

In the constructor from `SurveyService` I load some data.

```
constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {

    this.finishedSurveys = [];

    this.loadCurrentSurvey();

    this.loadFinishedSurveys();

 }
```

I put also the `SurveyService` into the `app.module`:

```
.....providers: [SurveyService].....
```

But the component loads before service so I haven no data in my component. Why does it happen? Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: How to load data before rendering the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component)

Comment: That would be happening because you requests in service's constructor may be asynchronous. If you want to wait for data to be loaded before your component loads then use resolvers instead

Comment: Service actually does load before the component, it's just that your data is not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use resolve for the angular router. E.g.
Make a class APIResolver like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './api.service';

import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class APIResolver implements Resolve<any> {
 constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
   return this.apiService.getItems(route.params.date);
 }
}
```

Then, resolve your corresponding router like

```
{
 path: 'items',
 component: ItemsComponent,
 resolve: { items: APIResolver }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this [link](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) to use OnInit

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    you call the service that you want to execute 
  }
}
```