# Angular 8 how do you execute service before page loads?

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I simply want to retrieve data before the page is loaded in order to be able to display this data.

user.service.ts

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getUserDetails(username) {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(`http://localhost:8080/users/` + username)
    .pipe(
      map(
        userData => {
          console.log(userData);
          return userData;
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

account.component.ts

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {
    this.username = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
    this.userService.getUserDetails(this.username);
  }

  logout() {
    this.authenticationService.logOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: You do realise, that `httpClient` makes an async call, but you're calling `getUserDetails` synchronously, right?

Comment: On `account.component.ts`, put what you did on the constructor on ngOnInit instead

Comment: you might be looking for a route resolver. https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/

Comment: @Eudz Now it wil come in the method getUserDetails() but it will do nothing? the console.log(userDate) is never reached?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2: How to load data before rendering the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655361/angular2-how-to-load-data-before-rendering-the-component)

Comment: You have to subscribe to `getUserDetail()`

Comment: @ShamPooSham Thank You I totally forgot but now the rest call is been reached :)

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, in order to get async data in my template I would simply do :

```
<div *ngIf="myData !== null">
…
</div>
```

This simple trick allows you to display async data without having errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a resolver in order to do that. A resolver is a class that implements `resolve<resolveType>` and uses one method `resolve`. In the `resolve` function, you can use injected service to returns an observable with your data :

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class userResolver implements Resolve<anu> {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any>| {
    return this.userService.getUserById(route.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
}
```

In this example, we inject the `userService` and use a method to returns an Observable. Please note that i'm using `any` to simplify here. In this case, the `route` parameters contains the current route we are trying to resolve. Let's say `/user/1`. We can use this object to retreive information about the current route, like the user Id.

Our resolver can then be used in the route of a particular page. It will be run before the `onInit` function of the page. To add it to a page, you need to call the function in the `resolve` portion of its route :

```
let route =  [
      {
        path: 'user/:id',
        component: UserComponent,
        resolve: {
          hero /* the name we will use in the onInit to get the data */: Resolver /* our resolver */
        }
      }
    ])
...
```

We can then access the resolved data in the `onInit` function :

```
export class UserComponent {
...
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit(){
         this.route.subscribe(data => {
             // we do something with our data.
         });
    }
}
```

You can get more information [at the official Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve);